# How to create booking according to its pitch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model pitch where i am fetching grounddetail_id. I want to show all the pitch available in the ground. How i can book pitch of ground..

## grounddetails_controller.rb

```
class GrounddetailsController < ApplicationController

 before_action :find_ground, only: [:show, :edit, :destroy, :update]

def index
 @grounddetails = Grounddetail.all.order('created_at DESC')
end

def new
 @grounddetail = Grounddetail.new
end

def edit
end

def show

end 

def create
  @grounddetail = Grounddetail.new(ground_params)
  if @grounddetail.save
   redirect_to @grounddetail
  else
   render 'new'
 end
end

def update
  if @grounddetail.update(ground_params)
    redirect_to @grounddetail
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

def destroy
  @grounddetail.destroy
   redirect_to root_path
end


private

  def find_ground
   @grounddetail = Grounddetail.find(params[:id])
  end

  def ground_params
   params.require(:grounddetail).permit(:name, :working_hours, :end_time, :address, :contact_no, :email, :number_of_grounds, :description, :featured_ground)
  end
end
```

## routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 devise_for :users
 devise_for :admins

 resources :grounddetails do 
   resources :pitches
 end


 root "grounddetails#index"
end
```

## model

grounddetail.rb

```
class Grounddetail < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :pitches, dependent: :destroy
end
```

pitch.rb

```
class Pitch < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :grounddetail
end
```

for now i just have pitch model and routes but in controller i am confused what to use. i can i book pitch of the ground. But for single ground i am able to book.

Answer (score 0):

In the `grounddetails#show` action

```
def show
  @pitches = @grounddetail.pitches
end
```

Then in the `groundetails/show.html.erb`, you can just use `<%= @pitches %>` to display the `pitches` of that `grounddetail`.

***Update:***

```
#in the show.html.erb

<% @pitches.each do |p| %>
  <%= form_tag book_pitch_path(p) do %>
  #your attributes here
  <%= submit_tag "Book this Pitch" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

#routes.rb
post :book_pitch/:id, to: 'pitches/book_pitch', as: 'book_pitch'

#in pitches_controller.rb

def book_pitch
  #your actions here
end
```

Comment: i am fetching number of pitches from grounddetail ...i am able to show it from grounddetail but don't know how to create booking for a pitch of a ground.

Comment: @AbhiShetAacharYeah What do you mean booking? Do you want to create a form to book each pitch?

Comment: yes...booking for pitch and it should be booking from it grounddetail_id

Comment: @pravin how can i do it if i don't wanna do with pitches controller and model...i have number of pitch column in grounddetail model..